# Text query against multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I use `text_phrase` query against multiple fields?

My case:
User types `hello world`. It title or content (or both) fields contain `hello (cool) world` -> return this document

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You an use the `boost` query to do so. You probably want to use the more advance form of the `text` query in order to providing boosting on the title (sometimes, it also makes sense to disable norms for the title doc, which makes the length of the field affect the scoring). Here is a full sample:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test -d '{
    "index.number_of_shards" : 1,
    "index.number_of_replicas" : 0
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/type/1 -d '{
    "title" : "hello (cool) world",
    "content" : "hello (cool) world"
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/type/2 -d '{
    "title" : "hello (cool) world",
    "content" : "xxx"
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/type/3 -d '{
    "title" : "yyy",
    "content" : "hello (cool) world"
}'

curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/_refresh

curl -XGET localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty -d '{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                {
                    "text" : {"content" : {"query" : "hello world"}}
                },
                {
                    "text" : {"title" : {"query" : "hello world", "boost" : 5}}
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```